# Specifying custom error messages on string validation in mongoose

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose

I am trying to validate a gender field which can either be male or female, so I used the mongoose "enum" validator for strings, but I cannot seem to figure out how to specify a custom error message to it.

I tried wrapping the enum in an array, like such:

enum: [["male", "female"], "custom error message]

Since this syntax is supported by other built in mongoose validation but to no avail.

I can write a custom validator to do the exact same thing using regex, but I was wondering if I'm missing something, because it seems a bit odd that I cannot specify an error message, and the mongoose docs are a bit sparse in that regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#built-in-validators) there isn't a straightforward way to do this. You will have to manually run `doc.validateSync()` to check for the errors.

However, based on the [solutions to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403907/mongoose-model-custom-error-message-for-enums/57058473#57058473) this should work:

```
gender: {
        type: String,
        enum: {
            values: ['male', 'female'],
            message: 'Your error message'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man, it solves it. i don't know why they leave out something like this, especially because it is not standard for them.